# Let $A,B \in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ invertible with $n$ impar. Then $AB+BA\not = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B \in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ invertible with $n$ impar. Then $AB+BA\not = 0$

**My work:**

Suppose $AB+BA=0$, then $AB=-BA$.
Then, $$det(AB)=det(-BA)\implies det(AB)=-det(BA)\implies det(AB)+det(BA)=0\implies det(A)det(B)+det(B)det(A)=0\implies 2det(A)det(B)=0\implies det(A)det(B)=0$$

If $det(B)\not =0$  then $det(A)=0$ this implies $A$ is not invertible. (Contradiction).

If $det(A)\not =0$  then $det(B)=0$ this implies $B$ is not invertible. (Contradiction).

In consequence,

$$AB+BA\not = 0$$

**Please if someone can review my proof i will be very grateful.**

Comment: Careful, $\det(bB)=(b)^nB$ where $b$ is a scalar. You don't use that $n$ is odd so...

Comment: In other word, you have to be careful on your first $\implies:$ $\det(AB)=det(-AB)\implies \det(AB)=(-1)^n\det(BA)=-\det(BA)$ because $n$ is odd.

Comment: You are welcome:).